# SQL query in PHP for checking if record exists

Tags: php, sql

I'm experiencing some odd behaviour with pre-check before adding a record.

How it works:
users can add records as MBI000000128 or MBI128. Becuase this refers to the same record i am doing checks. Currently if MBI128 already exists and user attempts to add MBI000000128 it should return 'record already exists message'.

Here's my issue:
I'm stripping all the zeros inside the string from MBI000000128 to MBI128 fine.
I have even echoed to make sure this is correct. There are no spaces before or after. I put single quotes to double check.

When i print the variable: `'MBI28'`

The record in the table exists as `'MBI128'`

Here's my SQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE pbi='$mbi_no_zeroes' ";
```

It continues to add the ticket to the table and i can't figure out why : /

Can somebody please advise on some more checks i can do or what i'm possibly doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: ZOMG! i've gone blind. i can't believe i couldn't see that! thanks mate.

Comment: What if they submit MBI1028 and MBI1280? Stripping zeroes makes those two completely different ids become the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$mbi_no_zeroes = str_replace("0", "", $mbi_no_zeroes);
$query = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE pbi='$mbi_no_zeroes' ";
```

See more about [str-replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)